# What is the pattern for using a context manager as with X() as foo then inspecting information from foo after it is used?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, contextmanager

I want to do something similar to this:

```
with open("a.txt"), 'w') as f:
    f.write("update1")
    raise Exception("Mocked error for this unit test")

assert f.closed == True
```

It's a dumb example, but the behavior I want is the `with X() as f` part to keep `f` around for inspection after the scope of the `with`.

Here's the behavior I would like to have in unit test form. I can't figure out how to get my desired behavior to pass:

```
with LogManager(self.tv) as lm:        
    # do some stuff
    raise Exception("Oh no! Unexpected Exception!")
self.assertIsNotNone(lm)
self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(lm.filepath))
```

I can get the behavior by doing the below, first assigning the return to a function, but I'd rather have the syntax of the `open as f`. I looked at the source of `open` and couldn't figure out how to replicate it.

```
lm = LogManager(self.tv)
with lm:
    # do some stuff
    raise Exception("Oh no! Unexpected Exception!")

self.assertIsNotNone(lm)
self.assertTrue(os.path.exists(lm.filepath)
```

## Attempted Solution 1

Attempted implementation of LogManager (stripped down to bare mechanics related to behavior I want to change):

```
class LogManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._result_file = None

    @property
    def filepath(self):
        return self._result_file

    def __enter__(self):
        self.tv._start_capture()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self._result_file = self.tv._stop_capture()
```

---

## Attempted Solution 2

This is essentially just the above, but in a verified runnable form outside of a unit test for people trying to help. Still doesn't work, but at least it's further stripped down.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals, print_function, nested_scopes

import os
from contextlib2 import ContextDecorator

class Manager(ContextDecorator):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter")
        self.a = "a"

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        print("exit")
        self.z = "z"
        return "hello"

try:
    n = Manager()
    print("next manager")
    j = ""
    with Manager() as m:
        j = m
        print("one thing")
        raise Exception("Oh no!")
        print("another thing")
except:
    pass

print(type(j))
print(type(m))
print(m.a)
print(m.z)
```

Output

```
next manager
enter
one thing
exit
<type 'NoneType'>
<type 'NoneType'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_context.py", line 48, in <module>
    print(m.a)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'
```